# Check length of a tuple by pattern matching

Tags: idris, idris2

I want to learn idris by writing a length function that checks the length of a tuple. I leanred a tuple is made by the MkPair constructor so I try to do pattern matching.

```
length : {t2:_} -> Pair t1 t2 -> Nat

length (MkPair a b) = case b of
                           MkPair c d => 1 + (length b)
                           _ => 2
```

```
Error: While processing right hand side of length. When unifying:
    t2
and:
    (?_, ?_)
Mismatch between: t2 and (?_, ?_).

coroutine:25:28--25:29
 21 |                            Pair c d => 1 + (length b)
 22 |                            _ => 2
 23 |
 24 |
 25 | length (MkPair a b) = case b of
                                 ^
```

What does the error mean? How do I fix it? In deed I'm not sure if I used the case syntax correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `b` is `t2` i.e. unknown, so you can't pattern match on it. You'd need to pattern match on `t2`. Once you've done that there's no need to pattern match on `b`.

BTW you're right about `MkPair` and `Pair` but they both have the shorthand `(·, ·)`

```
length : {t2 : _} -> (t1, t2) -> Nat
length (_, b) = case t2 of
                     (_, _) => 1 + (length b)
                     _ => 2
```